# How do I step though an array one cell at a time using onclick?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am new to JavaScript and am trying to create a function that changes the background color of my HTML document each time I click on a DIV.  The code I have just loops though my array all the way to the end instead of one loop per click on my DIV.  I know I am missing something that increments each time I click on the DIV, but can't figure out what.  In my HTML document I have a DIV

```
<div id="autoText" onclick="moveMe()"></div>.
```

Here is my JavaScript so far:

```
var multipleColors = [];

multipleColors[0] =  "red";
multipleColors[1] =  "blue";
multipleColors[2] =  "yellow";

function moveMe() {
for (i=0; i < multipleColors.length; i++) {
console.log("This is step " + i);
this.document.body.style.backgroundColor=multipleColors[i];
}
}
```

I would really appreciate anyone's advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue from the beginning of the after you reached its end, use %(modulo) operator:

```
var multipleColors = [];

multipleColors[0] =  "red";
multipleColors[1] =  "blue";
multipleColors[2] =  "yellow";
var current = 0;

function moveMe() {
    current++;
    var newIdx = current % multipleColors.length;
    this.document.body.style.backgroundColor = multipleColors[newIdx];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop, use a counter variable that you increase whenever the element is clicked:

```
var index = 0;

function moveMe() {
  console.log("This is step " + index);
  this.document.body.style.backgroundColor=multipleColors[index];
  index += 1;
}
```

If you want to continue from the beginning of the array after you reached its end, reset the variable:

```
var index = 0;

function moveMe() {
  console.log("This is step " + index);
  this.document.body.style.backgroundColor=multipleColors[index];
  index += 1;

  if (index === multipleColors.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
var multipleColors = [];

multipleColors[0] =  "red";
multipleColors[1] =  "blue";
multipleColors[2] =  "yellow";

function moveMe() {
    this.document.body.style.backgroundColor=(multipleColors[multipleColors.indexOf(this.document.body.style.backgroundColor)+1])?multipleColors[multipleColors.indexOf(this.document.body.style.backgroundColor)+1]:multipleColors[0];

}
```

You can keep adding the more colors in array.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8P75Z/)**

Comment: Your solution will only work when no other external factor changes the elements backgroundcolor

Comment: @Mark, if external factors changes backgroundcolor which is not present in given array then then it will show the red color which is first element of array multipleColors, so I don't think it will create any problem.

Comment: Down voters , kindly put comments. don't destroy the healthy environment :(

Comment: whoever it was ,this would not be appreciated, I do agree there might be flaws in my answer but one should point out the problem before down voting so that we could learn from him/her :(